# Error: Client must have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION on Pre-Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have this crash on my app on a device whose SDK is Android JellyBean (precisely v4.3).
The permission **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** is defined in the manifest and as far I know, this permission is automatically activated on Pre-Marshmallow devices.

**Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to perform any location operations.**

is the error I have in my firebase console. This crash only affected one user. I'd like to know if anyone has already encountered such a situation on Pre-Marshmallow, if so how can I solve it.

Comment: maybe that device has turned off GPS ?

Comment: okay @AliAhmed. Thanks for the feedback. But assuming that's the case how can I check that in my code i.e how can I determine if the GPS is off before performing any location update ??

Comment: just Google it, you will easily find code for checking GPS enabled/disabled. just 4-5 lines of code.

Comment: alright mate...I'll take a look !. Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: `public static boolean isGpsEnable(Context context) {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }`

Comment: Try above code. it was working for me, last time i used in my app.

Comment: copy that...thanks